# HP Pavilion onboard webcam is not working with Skype on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS what do I need to do to get it running?

Tags: skype, webcam

I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know all that much about this OS. Not a tech either. Just need someone to better explain to me how to get my webcam working. My micro phone works when connected to Skype. But not the cam. What can I do to fix this issue? and please remember I don't know all the tricks most of you already know.

Comment: I have been searching the web for a fix to this issue and have not found one. Everything I have found so far has been out of date. Or for earlier versions of Ubuntu. I just need to know how to get Skype to recognize my onboard webcam so it shows a video. Audio is working just fine. I get both audio and video with Cheese. So why am I not with Skype?